# How to change PostgreSQL layer encoding for QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-server, encoding

I'm actually stuck trying to update encoding of my PostgreSQL layers to be able to set my project as QGIS server project.

[image: QGIS server configration Check]

In the layers properties, I can't change the layer's encoding.

[image: Layer's encoding]

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the database encoding was right :

```
CREATE DATABASE sdis
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'French_France.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'French_France.1252'
```

The .qgs project was constructed with another database in another encoding. Then was switched to my actual database.

I reloaded the layers as new layers in the project and fetch the styles from the old ones.

Layer encoding is now correct.

[image: Encoding corrected]

Answer (score 2):

The PostgreSQL layers are stored within your database. Your database has a **specific encoding** set, so **the layers provided are in the same encoding as your database**.

Usually when creating a new database the encoding will be preset as the system one. I don't see any advantage of changing encoding on the fly, since it sounds quite resource hungry.

I would recommend changing the **encoding of the whole database**. 
The quickest way would be:

1. Dump your database with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html).
2. [Create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createdatabase.html) a new database with new encoding.
3. [Restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) the dumped database into your new database.

Hopefully it will restore without encoding errors.

You can read more about changing database encoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database).